# What is the purpose of overriding the method in the mock class in mockito

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, mockito

I am new to flutter and I have been trying to conduct unit testing in flutter using mockito. But there are some concerns which I can't understand and didn't find any solution in the Internet. For example, this is the code I have implemented for a sample class,

```
class User {
  final String name;
  
  User({required this.name});
}

 class UserService {
  User getUser() {
    return User(name: "sample user");
  }

  String getUserName() {
    return "sample name";
  }
}

class MockUserService extends Mock implements UserService {
  @override
  User getUser() {
    return super.noSuchMethod(
      Invocation.getter(#getUser),
      returnValue: User(name: 'Mock User'),
     
    ) as User;
  }

   @override
  String getUserName() {
    return super.noSuchMethod(
      Invocation.method(#getUserName,[]),
      returnValue: "mock name"
    ) ;
  }
}

void main(){
  test('test mock', () {
    var mockUserService = MockUserService();
     when(mockUserService.getUserName()).thenReturn("hello");
    print("U " +  mockUserService.getUserName());
  });
}
```

This works absolutely fine, but I don't get why do we need to override the getUser() and getUsername() methods inside the mock class? Since we will be already stubbing is there a need? Obviously I am getting an error(called: "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'") if I don't override it inside the mock class, but what is the reason to override it?

Even though I have overridden the methods inside the mock class and defined a return value still I am getting an error. For example, let's say it's the getUsername() I am testing and if I don't stub it inside the test I am getting an issue "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'". What is the reason for that? Why doesn't it return the value which is defined inside the mock class method? Why essentially do we need to stub and override the method while conducting a test?

Please any clarification on the above questions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: But stub will "do nothing" and your example you will throw NoSuchMethodException (i think, never did that before). The same can be done using `doAnswer`

Comment: @Antoniossss no I am not getting an error it runs fine with the above code

Comment: Idk if it is in Dart as well, but what would happen if you would do `doReturn("hello").when(serviceMock).getUserName()`? Will you still get NPE'like exception ?

Comment: Also I can see that here there is no example that looks like your https://pub.dev/packages/mockito (except using Fake, but you are not using it)

Comment: @Antoniossss hi, unfortunately, dart doesn't have suck kind of syntax from my knowledge. And yeah I was following a youtube tutorial of resocoder tdd in flutter. He is using the exact samething :(

Comment: [`Mock`s should *not* be overriding methods](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#best-practices).  Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: @jamesdlin because if i dont't do so I am getting an error called "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

Comment: @jamesdlin please refer to this https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md

Comment: @SHA *You* should not be overriding methods in `Mock`s.  You should just let `package:mockito` generate the `Mock` classes for you.  Or are you asking why the generated `Mock`s override methods?

Comment: @jamesdlin yeah even though we generate it using the GenerateMocks annotation, still those generated classes have overridden the methods. Yet manually mocking or letting mockito generate mock classes does the same thing. Why even mockito is overriding those methods?

Comment: The document you linked to [explains why already](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md#problems-with-typical-mocking-and-stubbing).  You ask, "Since we will be already stubbing is there a need?", but without the overrides, you cannot register stubs with null-safety.

Comment: @jamesdlin ok now I get it it's mostly because of the null safety feature. Thanks a lot. But I have another question, when we pass the Invocation inside the super.noSuchMethod, even if the member name which is passed to the Invocation constructor (eg: instead of #getUser I passed #test) is wrong it still completes the test successfully. Do you have any idea on this?